# How can I "specialize" a polymorphic type in Coq?

Tags: coq

(Note, my goal is to learn more about Coq, not necessarily solve this particular problem. IRL, I expect I would just refactor to remove the offending type in that situation.)

I have a type defined this way:

```
Inductive natprod : Type := pair (n1 n2 nat).
```

I want to make my product type polymorphic, so I now defined

```
Inductive prod {X Y : Type} : Type := pair (x : X) (y : Y).
```

However, I can't have both `prod` and `natprod` defined in the same module because they both have a constructor `pair`. But I have a bunch of functions and theorems for `natprod`, so I don't want to throw away `natprod`. Instead, I'd like to basically say "When I write `natprod`, what I mean is `prod nat nat`."

So I tried this:

```
Definition natprod := prod nat nat.
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Illegal application (Non-functional construction): 
The expression "prod" of type "Type" cannot be applied to the term
 "nat" : "Set"
```

How can I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the issue was that `X` and `Y` were defined to be implicit arguments to `prod`. We can solve this issue by forcing them to be explicit:

```
Definition natprod := @prod nat nat.
```

Alternatively,

```
Notation natprod := (@prod nat nat).
```

is more like a macro and does not need to be unfolded in proofs.

Comment: I would consider making `X` and `Y` *not* implicit arguments to `prod`. You should make them explicit arguments to `prod` and implicit arguments to `pair`.

Comment: What would that look like syntactically? `Inductive prod (X Y : Type) : Type := pair {X} {Y} (x : X) (y : Y)`?

Comment: `Inductive prod (X Y : Type) : Type := pair (x : X) (y : Y). Arguments pair {X Y} x y.`